# Vue changing the component without URL changes

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

I'm in Registration.vue component. The component contains registration form with email, password, etc.. fields.
I would like to thanks user for successful registering (with instruction that he should go check email).
What is the best solution to do this?

I was thinking about:

- redirecting to second component using `this.$router.push` or `this.$router.replace` but this will change URL and when somebody go this URL without registering he will see message that he should check email...
- replacing current component with other when registering action successful but I dont know how to do this (without URL change, and with good code).
- using `<component v-bind:is="currentView">` but I am not sure if this is best solution. I need to make three files (for parent component with :is, for form and for thanks). Also i need to emit event from child that registration went well, but on the other hand i should fire vuex registration action and dont expect for response (see the next sequence)

The other thing is that we should not wait for the vuex action to be completed, but i need to know if registration went well - https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/46#issuecomment-174539828

I am using vue.js 2, vue-router, vuex

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [Sweet Alert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/blob/master/README.md) to display a success or error dialog. It supports [Ajax requests](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#ajax-requests) so you can display a "your registration is processing, please check your email" message while it is being handled.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach is suitable when user successfully registers and then redirected to login page.

Now issue how to check whether user has entered required field? So there comes form validations. You can use vee-validate plugin and it's perfect for all projects. I am using it and it has so many available validations.

With these UI validations, after they are passed successfully then only submit action will be fired or else user will be prompted for entering required field.

You can see basic example here - http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/index.html#basic-example

When action is performed,

```
 ///main.js
 ...
 Vue.use(VeeValidate)
 ...


 // register.vue
 this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {

    if (result) {
       //done
       this.$router.replace( '/login' );
    }
    else{
        // throw error
    }
```

Simple as that. 
Try this approach if you want the UI validations on the form.